# AngularJs orderby filter not sorting data correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of customer displayed in html using ng-repeat from controller.

Here I am trying to sort the data using orderby filter. But the problem is when the array initialized it is sorted correctly in Ascending order. But when I click on Name heading it chnages the data but does not descends the  data as expected. Here is a running plunker:

http://plnkr.co/4aAH08bzVUnws5RRx5RP

AngularJs:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.sortIt = "name";
  $scope.reverse = false;

  $scope.customers = [
                            {
                                name:'AAA',
                                city: 'Dublin',
                                orderTotal: 9.9563,
                                joined: '1947-10-10'},
                            {
                                name:'CCC',
                                city:'London',
                                orderTotal: 24.999,
                                joined: '2011-08-12'},
                            {
                                name:'BBB',
                                city:'Kenya',
                                orderTotal: 140.4852,
                                joined: '1981-06-04'},
                            {
                                name:'DDD',
                                city:'Tokyo',
                                orderTotal: 77.3654,
                                joined: '2006-10-30'}
                        ]

  $scope.doSort = function(propName) {
    $scope.sortIt = propName;

    //changing the value to opposite if true then false, if false then true
    $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse; 
  }
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ng-click="doSort(name)" class="btn-arrange">
            Name
          </th>
          <th>
            <span>City</span>
          </th>
          <th>Order Total</th>
          <th>Joined</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="c in customers | orderBy: sortIt: reverse">
          <td>{{c.name}}</td>
          <td>{{c.city}}</td>
          <td>{{c.orderTotal}}</td>
          <td>{{c.joined}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: What is problem with resultant table?

Comment: I want to sort by name in ascending and descending order, when table initialize name are sorted correctly. But when i click on name heading it is not descending the names correctly!!

Comment: It is working correctly for me. Did you update code later?

Comment: the name field is not descending correctly please see again. I have updated the name field data with basic a, b, c,d value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `$scope.reverse = !scope.reverse;` with `$scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;`

You missed `$` before `scope`.

**Update:**

Replace `<th ng-click="doSort(name)" class="btn-arrange">` with `<th ng-click="doSort('name')" class="btn-arrange">`

[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/oeWBaXlGGf4YFDplBOou?p=preview)

Comment: I have updated the code now click is working. But still it is not sorting in asc/desc as expected. any help on that pls!!!!

Comment: @Sam Updated answer.

Comment: thanks..maybe i had option to give you 5 points on this.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am adding this answer to do the sorting for all individual heading values with predicate

```html
<th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'name'; reverse=!reverse">Name</a> </th>
<th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'city'; reverse=!reverse">City</a> </th>
<th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'orderTotal'; reverse=!reverse">Order Total</a></th>
<th><a href="" ng-click="predicate = 'joined'; reverse=!reverse">Joined</a></th>

<tr ng-repeat="c in customers | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
<td>{{c.name}}</td>
<td>{{c.city}}</td>
<td>{{c.orderTotal}}</td>
<td>{{c.joined}}</td>
```